# HammerJS not working with Angular Material 2 tabs on mobile.

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material2, hammer.js

I'm Trying to integrate swipe gestures in Angular material 2(Angular5). It is working with mouse on desktop. The problem is that when I use mobile(Chrome) it only senses the gesture on labels of tabs.

**Template Code:**

```
<mat-tab-group mat-scroll-y (swipeleft)="swipe($event.type)" (swiperight)="swipe($event.type)" class="home-tabs" mat-stretch-tabs [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex">
    <mat-tab label="Home">
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
      </ng-template>
      <app-my-cars></app-my-cars>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Registered Cars">
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <mat-icon>directions_car</mat-icon>
      </ng-template>
      <app-registered-cars></app-registered-cars>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Unregistered Cars">
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <mat-icon>directions_car</mat-icon>
      </ng-template>
      <app-unregistered-cars></app-unregistered-cars>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

**Component Code:**

```
export class DashboardHomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  selectedIndex: number = 0;
  totalTabs: number = 3;
  SWIPE_ACTION = { LEFT: 'swipeleft', RIGHT: 'swiperight' };
  swipe(eType) {
    console.log(eType)
    if(eType === 'swipeleft' && this.selectedIndex < this.totalTabs){
      this.selectedIndex += 1;
    }
    else if(eType === 'swiperight' && this.selectedIndex > 0){
      this.selectedIndex -= 1;
    }
  }

}
```

[image: Demo]